# Return an instance of generic type from its Class

Tags: java, generics, types, instantiation

My classes are :

```
public class Module {}
public class WorkerModule extends Module{}
public class WalkerModule extends Module{}
```

I have a module factory with a static method to create modules :

```
public static Module initializeModule(Class<? extends Module myClass) {
    Module module = null;
    try {
        module = myClass.newInstance();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        throw new ModuleException(e);
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        throw new ModuleException(e);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new ModuleException(e);
    }

    return module;
}
```

It works, but I would like to improve it by using generic types.
I still need my method to return an instance of my class parameter, which I want to force to be a child of Module class.
I don't know how to change my method's declaration.
Maybe something like this:

```
public static <T> T initializeModule(Class<T extends Module myClass) {}
```

but clearly, it's not that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static <T extends Module> T initializeModule(Class<T> myClass) {
    T module = null;
    try {
        module = myClass.newInstance();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        throw new ModuleException(e);
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        throw new ModuleException(e);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new ModuleException(e);
    }
    return module;
}
```

Comment: I would like to force myClass to extends Module. Is it possible?

Comment: That's what `<T extends Module>` does. If you try do use a class that does not extend `Module` and the compiler will complain.

Comment: Ok, it's what I wanted. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

that would be something like this:

```
public static <T extends Module> T initializeModule(Class<T> myClass) {
    T module = null;
    try {
        module = myClass.newInstance();
    } catch (SecurityException e) { ...
    } catch (InstantiationException e) { ...
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) { ...
    }

    return module;
}
```